# Method Chaining for replacing row values and Broadcasting

Tags: python, pandas

I need to a way for searching and replacing row values based on criteria and multiply a column by some number using method chaining , i can do without method chaining but i wanted to know if its possible?

**Here's my initial code**

```
energy=(pd.read_excel((path0),skiprows=header,skipfooter=footer)
          .drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0','Unnamed: 1'],axis=1)
          .rename(columns={"Unnamed: 2": "Country", "Petajoules": "Energy Supply","Gigajoules":"Energy Supply per Capita","%":"% Renewable"})
```

**now i can do what i need like this**

```
energy.loc[energy['Energy Supply'] == "...", 'Energy Supply'] = np.NaN
energy["Energy Supply"] = 1000000 * energy["Energy Supply"]
```

but i want to be able to do the above using **method chaining**

Comment: 'Energy Supply' column:I think it's a whole column of these multiplied by 100,000.

Answer (score 0):

The nan values can be specified when reading the excel using the parameter 'na_values' [1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html). Use the less number of methods as possible.

```py
 pd.read_excel((path0), skiprows=header, skipfooter=footer, na_values='...')
```

You can create new variables using 'assign':

```py
df = (pd.DataFrame(list(range(5)), columns=['old'])
      .assign(new = lambda x: x['old']*1000)
     )
df
```

```
    old new
0   0   0
1   1   1000
2   2   2000
3   3   3000
4   4   4000
```